# Finding size of a test for $H_0: \theta \in [a,b]$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ be independent N(θ, $σ^2$) random variables. Determine t such that the test
δ = $\chi[\bar{X}< a - t\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}] + \chi[\bar{X}> b + t\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}]$
for testing $H_0$ : θ ∈ [a, b] versus $H_1$ : $θ \not{\in} [a, b]$ has size .05.

I think this test has power function;

$\pi_{\delta}(\theta)=P_{\theta}(Z < \frac{a-\theta}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}-t) + P_{\theta}(Z > \frac{b-\theta}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}+t) $

Now the size is defined to be the sup over all $\theta \in [a,b]$ and here I'm stuck.  I think this depends very much on the values of a,b; perhaps something like min{|a|,|b|} but this is just a guess based on doodles and I can't begin to think how to show something like this precisely.

Currently trying to write $\pi(\theta)=\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha(\theta)}\phi(x)dx - \int_{\beta(\theta)}^\infty\phi(x)dx$ with $\alpha(\theta)=\frac{a-\theta}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}-t, \beta(\theta)=\frac{b-\theta}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}+t$
So that $$\frac{d}{d\theta}\pi_{\delta}(\theta)=[\phi(\alpha(\theta))-\phi(\beta(\theta))](-\sqrt{\frac{n}{\sigma^2}})=0$$ iff $$\alpha(\theta)^2=\beta(\theta)^2$$

Is this the right approach? I'm suspicious for 2 reasons;

1) the quadratic that results from this suggests the critical values of $\theta$ depends on t, which intuitively I don't think that it can

2) the calculation is suspiciously long and  tedious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\pi(\theta)$ is a probability, so it is bounded by 1, but in the interval $[a,b]$ you can find another sharper bound (that's what you are looking for.) Note that whenever $\theta\to\infty$ or $\theta\to-\infty$, $\pi(\theta)\to 1$. This suggests that $\pi(\theta)$ has a U shape, with a minimum hopefully in $[a,b]$.

Let say that we prove or we are convinced that the minimum is always in $[a,b]$ and that in fact $\pi(\theta)$ has a U shape (I haven prove it, but used my intuition an R to convince myself.) Now, the supremum has to be on the border, i.e., $\theta=a$ or $\theta=b$. But, interestingly 
$$
\pi(a)=\pi(b).
$$
(Check this! I suppose that $t\geq 0$ and used that $P(Z\geq z)=P(Z\leq -z)$, $z\geq 0$, $Z\sim N(0,1)$.) Therefore, the supremum is $\pi(a)=\pi(b)$.

Finally, to find $t$ you will have that $\pi(a)=P(Z\leq \text{something that depends on t})=0.05$, and you can find the value of $t\geq 0$ that satisfies that.

To see that indeed $\pi(\theta)$ has a U shape centered at the middle $\theta_m=(a+b)/2$, just observe by simple substitution that (I always assume $t\geq 0$)
$$
\alpha(\theta_m) = -\beta(\theta_m).
$$
Since $\phi(x)=\phi(-x)$, then $\frac{d}{d\theta}\pi(\theta)\Big|_{\theta=\theta_m}=0$.

Now, let $\theta(\epsilon)=\theta_m+\epsilon$, $\epsilon>0$. In this case
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta}\pi(\theta)\Big|_{\theta=\theta(\epsilon)}=C\left(\phi\left(\alpha_0-\epsilon\sqrt{n/\sigma^2}\right)-\phi\left(-\alpha_0-\epsilon\sqrt{n/\sigma^2}\right)\right),
$$
where $C<0$ and $\alpha_0=\alpha(\theta_m)<0$. Since $-\alpha_0>0$, a patient observation to this expresion confirms that the derivative is positive for any $\epsilon$. On the other hand, redefining $\theta(\epsilon)=\theta_m-\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$, one gets 
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta}\pi(\theta)\Big|_{\theta=\theta(\epsilon)}=C\left(\phi\left(\alpha_0+\epsilon\sqrt{n/\sigma^2}\right)-\phi\left(-\alpha_0+\epsilon\sqrt{n/\sigma^2}\right)\right),
$$
and the same conclusion can be drawn, just that the derivative is negative.

In conclusion, in the middle, $\pi(\theta)$ reaches its minimum, and moving to the right is increasing and to the left decreasing, i.e., it has a U shape. So the supremum is reached in either $a$ or $b$.

Comment: It cannot be strictly U shape as I get 2 critical points for $\pi_{\delta}(\theta)$.

Comment: @Muselive What are your two critical values? What my answer suggests is that the supremum is in the extremes of the interval. Note that your derivative is zero in the middle of the interval and change signs moving to left or right of the middle.

Comment: The zeros of $\alpha(\theta)^2-\beta(\theta)^2$

Comment: They aren't kind.

Comment: @Muselive What I said in the previous comment is true. Let me edit my answer to show you. If you find any mistake, please let me know.